# Sorting Numbers without built-in or imported function to sort the list or calculate the mean

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a Python 3 application that contains a user-defined function called Sort_and_Mean. The Sort_and_Mean function should:

- it is supposed to output the result as a comma-separated list without the square bracket.
- Be able to exit by typing exit.

Already Completed:
- sort and return a list of numbers that are passed to it
- calculate and return the mean value of the list.

I tried removing brackets but that did not work.

```
import sys
def sort_and_mean(number):
    for index in range(1,len(number)):
        value = number[index]
        i = index - 1
        while i>=0:
            if value < number[i]:
                number[i+1] = number[i]
                number [i] = value
                i = i - 1
            else:
                break
    return number



number = " "
while True:
    print("\nSorting Numbers in Python 3 Program")
    if (number == "exit" or number == "Exit" or number == "EXIT"):
        print("Goodbye")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        number = input("Enter a the value or type Exit to exit: ")
        number = [int(v) for v in number.split(',')]
        print("Original List: ", number)
        print("Sorted List: ", sort_and_mean(number))
        print ("Mean Value:", "%0.2f" % (sum(number) / len(number)))
```

EXPECTED:
- Original List: 3,9,7,4,0,2
- Sorted List: 0,2,3,4,7,9
- Mean Value: 4.17

EXIT RESULTS:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/antoniocazarez/Desktop/sortingnumbers.py", line 25, in <module>
    number = [int(v) for v in number.split(',')]
  File "/Users/antoniocazarez/Desktop/sortingnumbers.py", line 25, in <listcomp>
    number = [int(v) for v in number.split(',')]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'exit'
```

RESULT:
Original List:  [3, 9, 7, 4, 0, 2]
Sorted List:  [0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9]
Mean Value: 4.17

Comment: Well you're not handling what happens when the user enters the string `'exit'` which is what the error is telling you, also this question is really similar to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54156837/sorting-numbers-in-python-3

Comment: Perfect. I fix it. Thank you!